# How to allow the admin to maintain content on this model

Tags: django, wagtail

I am using Django/Wagtail

I have a form and would like to allow the admin to be able to edit field titles and help text

**models.py**

```
class FoodDiaryItem(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user_pk = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0,)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    level_of_hunger = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True,
                                               default=0,
                                               validators=[
                                                   MaxValueValidator(5),
                                                   MinValueValidator(0)
                                               ])
    ...
```

**food_diary_item.html**

```
<form action="/food-diary/diary-updated/{{ food_diary_item.id }}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr><td class="text-right">Food Diary item for:</td><td>{{ user.username }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="text-right">Date:</td><td>{{ food_diary_item_form.date }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="text-right">Time:</td><td>{{ food_diary_item_form.time }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="text-right">Level of hunger:</td><td>{{ food_diary_item_form.level_of_hunger }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="text-right"> </td><td>before eating (rate from 0-5, 0=no hunger, 5=starving)</td></tr>
        ...
```

Is there any way that I can re-organise the model to make the text admin maintainable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are to be displayed on a page, then you could add override labels to that page's fields.

If the form fields are to be reused but overridden globally, or on a per-site basis then you could add some [Wagtail Site settings](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8/reference/contrib/settings.html), e.g.

```py
@register_setting
class FoodDiaryFormSettings(BaseSetting):
    level_of_hunger = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then in your template refer to them:

```
        <tr><td class="text-right">{% firstof settings.app_label.FoodDiaryFormSettings.level_of_hunger "Level of hunger" %}:</td><td>{{ food_diary_item_form.level_of_hunger }}</td></tr>
```